# keep localStorage values after refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When I add "Item" to localStorage, and when I refresh the page, everything is fine. But, when I want to add new item, everything starts from the beginning in "ToDo" localStorage.

```js
let ToDo = [];

let addNew = (event) => {

  let onelist = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: title.value,
    description: desc.value,
    cat: [],

  }

  for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
    if (checkbox.checked)
      onelist['cat'].push(checkbox.value);
  }
  ToDo.push(onelist);
  window.localStorage.setItem('ToDo', JSON.stringify(ToDo));
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('AddItem').addEventListener('click', addNew);
});
```

Comment: Where is your `const ToDo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ToDo"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You never read from local storage. Maybe you could do something like this:

```js
// ... your other code

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ToDo = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('ToDo'));
  document.getElementById('AddItem').addEventListener('click', addNew);
});
```

Comment: I already commented this but it is not enough. This will fail when there is nothing in localStorage

Comment: I already wondered what the downvote was for. I saw your comment right after I posted my (wrong) answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: No sorry. I voted you down because I wanted OP to be able to close and delete the question, but then I saw another answer identical to yours and decided to answer. I removed the vote

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your localStorage item and edit it

ex:

```
const ToDo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ToDo"))
// now work on the ToDo like ToDo.push(...)
// after done save it again to the storage
 localStorage.setItem('ToDo', JSON.stringify(ToDo));
```

what your doing is you're recreating the storage all over again every addNew call

Comment: I already commented this but it is not enough. This will fail when there is nothing in localStorage

Comment: thats why you should check if its already exist or not and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to answer because it is a little more complex

You need to see if there is something in localStorage and if there is, use it.

You cannot JSON.parse `undefined` or `null` so a test is needed

```
const lcTodo = localStorage.getItem("ToDo");
ToDo = lcTodo ? JSON.parse(lcTodo) : [];
```

It can live in the load

```js
let ToDo;

let addNew = (event) => {

  let onelist = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: title.value,
    description: desc.value,
    cat: [],

  }

  for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
    if (checkbox.checked)
      onelist['cat'].push(checkbox.value);
  }
  ToDo.push(onelist);
  window.localStorage.setItem('ToDo', JSON.stringify(ToDo));
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const lcTodo = localStorage.getItem("ToDo");
  ToDo = lcTodo ? JSON.parse(lcTodo) : [];
  document.getElementById('AddItem').addEventListener('click', addNew);
});
```